# Sharing screenshot page via navigate.share in web

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to share the screenshot of a web page(using **htmltocanvas**) then share it via **navigate.share**?

Comment: well, i think you could but with 3 steps. 
you should first convert the html to canvas, then convert the canvas to image then convert the image to file object and send it to the navigate.share api.

Comment: @arielb i tried that, but it seems the share api only work for filelist object its not working for file object, and i dont know how to create a filelist object from a blob or file, can you able to help me?